# Why does $N(\mathfrak p)$ belong to $\mathfrak p$?

Tags: ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

> Why does $N(\mathfrak p)$ belong to $\mathfrak p$ ?

$N(\mathfrak p)$ is the norm of the prime ideal $\mathfrak p\in\mathcal O$ defined as $N(\mathfrak p)=|\mathcal O/\mathfrak p|=$(say $p$)

Now since every prime ideal is maximal in the ring of integers, we have $\mathcal O/\mathfrak p$ is a field, hence of prime characteristic $p\in\mathbb Z$, is then $p\mathcal O$ prime, then I could say: If $p\mathcal O$ and $\mathfrak p$ share any elements then by maximality $p\mathcal O\subset \mathfrak p$ and thus $p\in\mathfrak p$, if not again by maximality $p\mathcal O+ \mathfrak p=\mathcal O$... Can I use a cardinality argument here ?

Comment: Why in a finite field $F$ of order $q$ does $q = 0$ in $F$?  Think about the characteristic.

Comment: looks like duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/502149/on-the-absolute-norm-of-an-ideal